# Using pipes in Angular 2 to filter on checkboxes

Tags: angular

I am trying to figure out how I could build a live filter of products using Angular and Pipes. In my html I have this loop for the products:

```
<div *ngFor="#product of products | filter">
    <div class="product">{{product.id}}</div>
</div>
```

It seems that I could add arguments to the filter function by typing filter:argument, what I wonder is how I could add an argument containing the value from an input field on the page. I would like to change things in the filter depending on if a

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

is checked or not. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a local template variable:

```
<input #ref type="checkbox">
```

Pass the value to your filter:

```
<div *ngFor="#product of products | filter: ref.checked">
    <div class="product">{{product.id}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you want `ref.checked`.

Comment: I like this solution! On further question: How do I trigger the filter on change of the checkbox?

Comment: Specify pure:false in your pipe declaration

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with your typescript code.
Example:

Make an empty array named products and method for this operation:

```
  products: any = [];

      onCheck(value){

    if(this.locations.includes(value) ){
        let index = this.locations.indexOf(value);
        this.locations.splice(index,1);
        console.log(this.locations);    
    }
 else{
    this.locations.push(value);
    console.log(this.locations);
 }    
   }
```

in html:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="product" value="burger" #burger (change)="onCheck(burger.value)">

    <input type="checkbox" name="product" value="pizza" #pizza (change)="onCheck(pizza.value)">
```

Eventhough, its is litle bit long but It will make things easy for filteration work

Answer (score 2):

Pass a component property that is bound to the checkbox using `NgModel`:

```
@Pipe({name: 'filter'})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(products, args:string[]) : any {
    return products.filter(product => {
      if(args[0]) {
        return product.id > 1;
      }
      return product.id;
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  pipes: [FilterPipe],
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="#product of products | filter:enableFilter">
    <div class="product">{{product.id}}</div>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="enableFilter"> enable filter
  <p>{{enableFilter}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
  enableFilter = false;
  products = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
  constructor() { console.clear(); }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/maTEP5qa3vQqJrrq9yW3?p=preview)</kbd>

If nothing in the component logic needs to know the value of the checkbox, I like @pixelbits's answer.